# How to place an if statement inside a concurrent block in Hacklang?

Tags: hacklang

Say I have 3 asynchronous functions A,B, and C.
I want to run them concurrently inside a concurrent block, but for one of the functions I want to check a condition. I'm looking for the following behaviour:

```
concurrent {
    await A(...);
    await B(...);
    if ($some_condition) {
        await C(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [an async block](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/asynchronous-operations/blocks):

```
concurrent {
    await A(...);
    await B(...);
    await async {
        if ($some_condition) {
            await C(...);
        }
    };
}
```